# Excel2013 と 2016 VSTO アドイン VisualC# での開発において特定処理でExcelが0xc0000374で終了する

Tags: c#, vba, excel

Excel2013 と 2016 VSTO アドイン VisualC# での開発において特定処理でExcelが0xc0000374で終了する

お世話になります

Excelのアドイン作成において特定処理でExcelが落ちることがわかったのですが、
原因や対処方法がわからず行き詰まっております。
最小限の処理で再現させることまでできたので質問させてください。

環境
Windows 10 Pro 21H2
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.9.47
Microsoft .NET Framework 4
Micosoft Office Standard 2019

VisualStudio新規プロジェクトで
Excel2013 と 2016 VSTO アドイン VisualC#
をつかってプロジェクト作成

プログラム詳細

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

namespace ExcelAddInMinimumError
{
    public partial class MyRibbon
    {
        private void MyRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExec_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is RibbonButton)
            {
                RibbonButton btn = (sender as RibbonButton);
                btn.Enabled = false;
                Globals.ThisAddIn.ShowRubyEditDialog();
                btn.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddInMinimumError
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void ShowRubyEditDialog()
        {
            Excel.Range cell = this.Application.ActiveCell;
            if (cell == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // 編集中ではないようにするため代入処理をする
            // これを入れると特定操作で落ちる(エクセルデータ次第だけど用意したテストデータでは連続でこの関数の処理をさせていると落ちる)
            cell.Activate();

            int colomnCount = cell.Column;
            int rowCount = cell.Row;
            for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rowCount; ++rowIndex)
            {
                string wk = Convert.ToString(this.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colomnCount].Value2);
                if (wk == "Text")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (wk == "Ruby")
                {
                    colomnCount = colomnCount - 1;
                    cell = this.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells[rowCount, colomnCount] as Excel.Range;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(cell != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cell.Characters.Count; ++i)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        #region VSTO で生成されたコード

        /// <summary>
        /// デザイナーのサポートに必要なメソッドです。
        /// コード エディターで変更しないでください。
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

このようなプログラムとなっております。
再現方法として

1. VisualStudioから実行後Excelを開く
   [image: Excel開いた状態]
2. アドインを選択
   [image: アドイン選択]
3. D4セルを選択
4. 実行ボタンを何度もクリックする(ここは不定回数となります)と
   `プログラム '[6960] excel.exe' はコード -1073740940 (0xc0000374) で終了しました。`となってデバッグが終了する

落ちるのがExcelであるのと0xc0000374というエラーがSTATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTIONなので原因がわからずじまいです。

何が原因なのかや、このようなときのデバッグ手法など教えていただければ幸いです

=============================================

2022/07/05追記
VSTOの問題かと思っておりましたが、ExcelVBAで似たような処理を作った結果落とすことが可能なのがわかりましたのでVSTOの問題ではなくExcelの問題のようです。

VBA内容

```
Option Explicit

' VSTOで最小で落ちる処理をVBAに持ってきた
Sub execute()
On Error GoTo execute_Error
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim val As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Characters
    
    Set cell = Application.ActiveCell
    
    ' VBAではCELL編集中では関数呼び出せないけどVSTOでは呼び出せてしまいカーソルが荒ぶるのでActivateして編集状態を解除
    cell.Activate
    
    Set cell = Nothing
    Set cell = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 3)
    
    For j = 1 To cell.Characters.Count Step 1
'        Set c = Nothing
'        Set c = cell.Characters(j, 1)
    Next j
    
    Set cell = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
execute_Error:
    Call MsgBox(Err.Number, vbInformation, Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Comment: 例えばこんな記事が調査を進める参考になるでしょう。[ヒープコラプションのデバッグ手順 ～ 例外 STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION (0xc0000374)](https://www.keicode.com/debug/heap-corruption.php)

Comment: HEAP_CORRUPTION って要はメモリ破壊が起きてるって事ですよね。Excel関連のCOMオブジェクトが解放されなくてメモリリークが発生していないでしょうか？リソースモニタでメモリ使用量を観察してみては。

Comment: [Releasing COM objects: Garbage Collector vs. Marshal.RelseaseComObject](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2020/07/20/releasing-com-objects-garbage-collector-marshal-relseasecomobject/) [OfficeをCOM Object経由でPowershellから扱うのはそれほど面倒じゃありませんでした](https://qiita.com/SilkyFowl/items/b4b6271619bd6d3824f7)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-automatically-fill-ranges-with-incrementally-changing-data?view=vs-2022
あたりのサンプルを見てる限り開放処理周りは一切ないようなのですが、開放しないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 解放した場合としない場合でメモリ使用量を比較してみればすぐ判るのではないでしょうか。

Comment: サンプルのデータでは複数回処理しないと落ちないデータですが、一回の処理で落ちるデータもあるので(実務用データのためサンプルとして提示できない状況…見せれるデータで一回で落ちるデータを作ろうとしてますが現在できてない)のでメモリ開放は関係ない気もします。ただ、開放処理を入れると落ちやすくなった気もします(ここらへんは理解不足なので試していくしかなさそう)

Comment: メモリ解放せずに何度も処理するとたしかにちょっとずづ増えていってる気はしますが、1MB単位ではなさそう(その前に落ちる)。そして増える原因が単にメモリキャッシュしてるだけなのかもわからないという感じです。Microsoft公式HPの初めての Excel 用 VSTO アドインを作成するにおいて開放処理は一切書かれていないので本当に開放しないといけないのかがわかってません。とはいえ、まずは開放処理入れて増えないことを確認していったりして検証をしていきます。(最終的に開放処理を入れた処理を記事に追加していきます。

Comment: 何度もクリックすると落ちると書かれているので、メモリリークによるメモリ不足とかを疑ったんですが、一回目でも発生する事もあるのであれば、ちょっと原因が違うかもしれませんね。cell.Activateで例外が発生した後、タイミングずらして再度呼び出せば成功するとかなら、呼び出すとまずいタイミングのようなものがあるのかもしれませんが…